# How to get .swf file from Rails Asset Pipeline without helper methods?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a Rails/React app that is not making use of the react-rails gem. The code is separated into two directories - one for the FE and one for the BE. I have been tasked to create an embedded cross-browser solution for a webcam to record videos and have already implemented the solution for Chrome/FF (using the webRTC API) and that is working well. The difficulty I have come across, which many people seem to have as well, is trying to implement this to work for Safari and IE.

I have found what seems like a decent implementation using flash and so I would like to include this in my project. The problem I am having, is serving the .swf file to the React code. Since the FE code is split up from the BE code, I am not using Rails Views for any of my FE code. The HTML DOM element needs data="path_to_swf_file" but I get a 422 error when I have the file in the public directory in Rails. Does anyone know the best way to handle this? Should I create a controller for this and just serve the .swf file that way? Can I simply access the public folder from my React code even though it is split from the Rails views?

Side Question: Does anyone know of a enterprise solution that can integrate with React/Rails? I figure it might be best do go this route if implementing it myself proves to be too cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a turn-key answer for this problem, but here are two approaches, that might do the trick:

- from within your JS code, load the `manifest.json` that's generated by the Rails asset pipeline to look up the path to the asset. That way you can look up the full path to the SWF file, including the digest.
- if you can live with a request to a Rails controller, you might want to consider not serving the file itself, but only the asset path to it. That way, if you decide to start using a CDN, it will still work and the file doesn't need to be served by your application server. Also, this might be a use case for [action caching](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching).

Posting this as an answer so it's more readable. But if anyone with more experience in React on Rails without `react-rails` has a better solution, I'm interested in that myself :)